# How can I use jQuery effects on Ajax loaded content?

Tags: php, jquery

Hi and thanks for taking some time to look at my question. I have a part of the page where content is dynamicly loaded into from another file. Reason for this is it needs to be live updated. Now I want to be able to apply jquery effects that are usually used for show/hiding content (slide, fade etc) to animate the difference between the current data and the new data. This is the code used to get the content and load it into the div:

```
    function k() {
        $.post("../includes/ajaxAgenda.php", {
            limit : value
        }, function(data) {
            $('#tab-agenda').html(data);
        });
    };
        $(document).ready(function() {
        k();
        $('#tab-agenda').scroll(function() {
            loadMore();
        });
    });
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        k();
    }, 1000);
```

So I guess my question is how do I animate what gets loaded in so it doesn't just "pop" from one content to another?

edit: I tried using the .live instead of .scroll but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#tab-agenda').live("scroll",function() {
        alert("hi"); 
        loadMore();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `live` function of jquery to bind the dynamically added elements.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Try this :

```
$('#tab-agenda').live("scroll",function() {
            loadMore();
        });
```

Comment: +1. This is often overlooked, and can make you go crazy trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks, but the loading in new content is not a problem. I already use 
       function loadMore() {
   if($('#tab-agenda').scrollTop() + $('#tab-agenda').height() == $('#itemlist').height()) {
    value = value + 1;
    k();
   }
  };


         $('#tab-agenda').scroll(function() {
    loadMore();
   });

to add more content, I want to animate the content added. Or if I change it to live I will be able to animate it?

Comment: To bind newly added content you need `live` else it wont bind to document, so you can not use it in your jquery.

Comment: So wherever you work with dynamically generated elements use `live` else it will not work

Comment: Hm, I tried it but it doesn't work anymore. $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#tab-agenda').scroll(function() {
    loadMore();
   });
  });
This is what I used and it worked, but with live it doesn't. I tried alerting something and it doesn't do anything on scroll

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add the ajax loader image with proper css over the content/ div as like below.

```
          function loadmore(){
          $("#loader").css('display','block');
           //your   
           //code 
           //here
           $("#loader").css('display','none');  
          }

         html 
         <img id="loader" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display:none" />
         <div id="content">
               your cont to display
          </div>
```